# How to delete dbfs Filestore files using CD pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, pipeline, delete-file

I want to delete the files from **dbfs Filestore** using the CD pipeline in **Devops**.Currently I tried with Delete file activity in Agent Job however its **Local Root Folder** is pointing to Git repository, whereas I want to delete from dbfs path. How to do that ?

Comment: Probably use the databricks cli? https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/fs-commands.html#remove-a-directory